# Extend a module from Map in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml

I have a module `StringMap` built by the functor `Map.Make` given a type `String`:

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
```

Besides the ordinary operations provided by `Map`, I would like to add more definitions in this module, for instance, `my_own_function`, such that I could call `StringMap.my_own_function`. Does anyone know where I should define this kind of functions and their signature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `include` keyword inside a new module to add all the same functions. This was also  extended to the [signature in OCaml 3.12](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc82).

```
module StringMap =
    struct
        include Map.Make(String)
    end
```

If you want to access the structure of the map, you'll have to add some `Obj.magic` or the `%identity` special external function. The redefinition of the type must be exact since no type checking is happening,

```
module Make (Ord : Map.OrderedType) =
    struct
        include Map.Make(Ord)

        type 'a impl = Empty 
                     | Node of 'a impl * key * 'a * 'a impl * int

        external impl_of_t : 'a t -> 'a impl = "%identity"
        external t_of_impl : 'a impl -> 'a t = "%identity"

        let cardinal map =
            let rec cardinal = function
                | Empty -> 0
                | Node(l,_,_,r,_) -> cardinal l + 1 + cardinal r
            in
            cardinal (impl_of_t map)

    end
```

Comment: This is not exactly the kind of things that you want to show to potential beginners asking Caml question. I don't think it is a good idea to present it as if it was a reasonable way to do. If you wish to expose a balanced tree implementation, please, do it (and Batteries does this with [BatAvlTree](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatAvlTree.html)), but breaking abstraction is not a good idea...

Comment: Totally agree, hopefully he finds the first part of the answer sufficient for his use.

Comment: @gasche: Do you refer to the second part of the answer? The first part with the `include` is considered idiomatic?